# Trying to scrape lists from Ebay website but unable to complete it

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have been trying to download these below lists from the ebay website.

```
Column 1: Item name
Column 2: item price
Column 3: Shipping price
```

But i am new to VBA and all i did and make is below code so far.

can someone please help me with this that how to scrape the required data from below link.

```
    Sub Web_Scraping()

  Dim Internet_Explorer As InternetExplorer
  Set Internet_Explorer = New InternetExplorer
  Internet_Explorer.Visible = True
  Internet_Explorer.navigate ("https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=045496902612+-Disc+-Only+-Refurbished+-Used+-Lot+-Import+-Japan+-Repro+-Reproduction+-Replacement+-VGA+-Graded+-Edition+-Edtion+-EU+-Mod+-Mods+-Moded+-modded+-Digital+-Collection+-Bundle+-Code+-Codes&LH_TitleDesc=0&LH_BIN=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc&LH_PrefLoc=1&LH_ItemCondition=3")
Do While Internet_Explorer.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
  MsgBox Internet_Explorer.LocationName & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Internet_Explorer.LocationURL
  
  
  
  For Each item In respJSON("QuickQuoteResult")("QuickQuote")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "A") = item("Item name")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "B") = item("item price")
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, "C") = item("Shipping price")
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Please have a look @FaneDuru

Comment: Note: Attempting to tag people that are not already part of the question does not accomplish anything.

Comment: Noted. and Understand well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have taken code from somewhere and tried to re-use it as is. It looks like from an answer where json was returned. For your current situation you are dealing with html and you need to understand html elements to facilitate your scraping.

For what you have shown you can use `classNames` to gather your elements and write them out. You can use `querySelectorAll` method of `ie.document` to apply the css class selector to grab 3 `NodeLists` (for your 3 requirements). Loop one list and index into all 3; write out to sheet.

```
Dim titles As Object, prices As Object, shipping As Object, i As Long

Set titles = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".s-item__title")
Set prices = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".s-item__price .POSITIVE")
Set shipping = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".s-item__logisticsCost")

With ActiveSheet
    Dim headers()
    
    headers = Array("Title", "Price", "Shipping")
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    
    For i = 0 To titles.Length - 1
        .Cells(i + 2, 1) = titles.Item(i).innertext
        .Cells(i + 2, 2) = prices.Item(i).innertext
        .Cells(i + 2, 3) = shipping.Item(i).innertext
    Next
End With
```

---

Read about css selectors: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Thank you so much @QHarr for helping me. I read about css selector but where to add the web link merge both code but its not working.